# Records truncated while importing from Microsoft Dynamics Marketing into Azure Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Datafactory and an Odataset to import contents from a Microsoft  Dynamics Marketing table into Azure Blob into the form of a JSON format text file. I am using the Odata feed from Microsoft Dynamics Marketing.

I have over a million line records, however I am observing that the import is being truncated at a million records. Is this a limit when importing using Azure datafactory?